# If 'ng-template' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ng-template>

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

> zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'ng-template' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ng-template' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ng-template' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
>   'ng-template' is not a known element:

I have applied this FIX in my App.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA}  from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        CKEditorModule,
        Ng2DatetimePickerModule,
        Ng2DragDropModule,
        DragulaModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        BootstrapModalModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})
    ],
    declarations: [something
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

PACKAGES.JSON

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },



"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
```

Even after this it is not working.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: Updated Packages in question

Comment: Did you create this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15860 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update angular-cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update
2. Update typescript and optionally your `@angular` packages. Your packages are pretty behind, most importantly `angular-cli`, so be prepared.

   - My core packages:

```js
dependecies: {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
  "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.10",
  "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^3.3.1"
}
devDependencies: {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
  "typescript": "^2.2.2"
}
```

3. `npm install @angular/material && npm install hammerjs —-save`

   - add `/node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js` in `angular-cli.json`
4. `MaterialModule`is deprecated https://github.com/angular/material2/releases

   - import individual modules into your `app.module`, and export accordingly then simply add tags to html

Answer (score 12):

`<ng-template>` was introduced in Angular4.

User either `<template>` or `<ng-container>`

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#installing-rc1
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15860

Comment: I checked the Link, But why it is showing in 2.2.1. Suddenly. Any alternative to avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps you're using a package that depends on Angular4?

Comment: No , if so please suggess

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the TS packages. I'm only using Dart myself.

Comment: It is only containing Angular 2.2.1 and associated dependencies, this time i have not included angular 4

Comment: The error message states that it found an `<ng-template>` which is only supported in Angular4. Somewhere in your code has to be an `<ng-template>`. Can you try using `grep` or similar tools to find where this element is used?

Comment: I checked , i didn't used ng-template anywhere, it may be accuring after compilation then cant say. 

I am using unpkg.com to transpile the TS Files, i am not using Node.js

Comment: Did you search the npm dependencies as well?

Comment: i am using online libraries from unpkg.com to transpile i am not using npm

Comment: There should still be a way to search them, for example using GitHub's seach.