# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'ng-template' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-promise, ng-template

After updating Angular2 app with 'npm install' and starting the server with 'npm start', I am getting this error

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ng-template' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-template' is an Angular component, then verify that it is 
part of this module.
2. If 'ng-template' is a Web Component then add 
"CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component 
to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ng-template> <div class="mat-
autocomplete-panel" role="listbox" [id]="id" 
[ngClass]="_getClassList()"): MdAutocomplete@0:0 ; Zone: <root> ; 
Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

I googled it and found that in angular4 template is represented with 'ng-template'.
I think some of my packages are dependent on Angular4, but I am unable to resolve this.

Could anyone here please help me.

Comment: could you share your code which causing error ?

Comment: If you use a `ng-template` try to use `ng-container` instead? But please share the code.

Comment: I am not sure which component is causing problem. I think after 'npm install' some dependencies get converted into angular4

Comment: @tschaka1904 may i know why so ? i mean to say like  why not to use `ng-template` ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43318507/5396827